# How to add a file greater than 100 mb in github

Tags: git, github

```
(base) ansel@ansel-GL63-9RCX:~/git_clone$ git push origin master
**Uploading LFS objects: 100% (1/1), 107 MB | 0 B/s, done.
Counting objects: 8, done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (7/7), done.
Writing objects: 100% (8/8), 26.91 MiB | 370.00 KiB/s, done.
Total 8 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: error: GH001: Large files detected. You may want to try Git Large File Storage
- https://git-lfs.github.com.
remote: error: Trace:
15fb6c187af5d2d3ebe2a38ebb23e88b5762675b9567da083d4f6f33164fc9e9
remote: error: See http://git.io/iEPt8g for more information.
remote: error: File flight_rf.pkl is 101.78 MB; this exceeds GitHub's file size limit
of 100.00**
```

I'm trying to add a file which has a size of 107 MB to GitHub.
Even though I'm using LFS it seems to show the aforementioned error.
Have I missed anything or is there a specific way to do this?

Comment: maybe you shouldn't [push file larger than 100 MB on github?](https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/github/managing-large-files/conditions-for-large-files), or push a link to somewhere?

Comment: You are using lfs? Probably the file is in the history of the project _prior_ to using lfs?

Comment: i just dragged and dropped the prior files.
This specific pickle file is of 107mb size so i cant drag and drop it.